# How to change a typename's signed-ness in template function c++

Tags: c++, bit-shift

So I've been trying to make a "looping" bitwise shift in c++ (11) and I have got the basic code down to this:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <limits> // is_signed
#include <limits.h> // CHAR_BIT

template<typename T>
T rotl(T input, unsigned int shift)
{
    return (input<<shift)|(input>>(sizeof(T)*CHAR_BIT-shift));
}

template<typename T>
T rotr(T input, unsigned int shift)
{
    return (input>>shift)|(input<<(sizeof(T)*CHAR_BIT-shift));
}

int main()
{
    int i = -5;

    std::printf( "%i\n", i);

    i = rotl(i, 4); // or other value
    std::printf( "%i\n", i);

    i = rotr(i, 4); // same value as above
    std::printf( "%i\n", i);
}
```

This gives me the expected behaviour when the output looks like the following:

```
-5
-1
-1
```

Because int i is signed, however if I do this to the code:

```
i = (int)rotl((unsigned int)i, 4);
. . .
i = (int)rotr((unsigned int)i, 4);
```

The output becomes:

```
-5
-65
-5
```

Which works like I want it too. I can also check the signed-ness of T using `numeric_limits` as following:

```
T rotr(T input, unsigned int shift)
{
    if(std::numeric_limits<T>::is_signed == false){
        return ()
    }else{
        return // problem here
    }
}
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to turn around the signed-ness of T, `(unsigned T)` is invalid for typenames. So how would I go about doing this? I would prefer not to use anything but the standard libraries (personal taste really), but if there's no plausible way to do it I might consider non std options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As  celticminstrel suggested use `std::make_unsigned<T>::type`

Here is how:

```
template<typename T>
T rotl(T input, unsigned int shift)
{
    typename std::make_unsigned<T>::type ii = static_cast<typename std::make_unsigned<T>::type>(input); 
    return static_cast<T>((ii<<shift)|(ii>>(sizeof(T)*CHAR_BIT-shift)));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the wait was because of heavy drinking (still drunk tbh), worked flawlessly for what I needed. Thank you all that contributed.

Comment: @MetroChild. No worries. Been there. :-)